# Setters and Getters in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to change the value of `trx` from another Activity when a button is pressed, what I've tried is

**ScoresActivity.kt**:

```
class ScoresActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

var trx = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores)
  }
}
```

**Other class:**

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

    when(p0){

        button_1 -> {
            ScoresActivity().trx = 5
        }
}
```

But whenever I print `trx`'s value it's 0.

Comment: here ScoresActivity() you created new instance of ScoresActivity.

Comment: activity is a component with it's own lifecycle you just cannot set a value in one activity from another. Read about Intent, SharedPreference(or any local storage e.g. sqlite) and startActivityForResult, one of these should suit your needs

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I see, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem:**

When you call `ScoresActivity()` you create a new instance of the `ScoresActivity` class. Since, you don't save this instance the setting of the value `trx` is lost.

**The solution:**
I am not sure what `trx` is supposed to represent, but since the `Activity` name gives a hint, I persume it is some kind of score (which then sould be available globally).

One way would be to put trx in a `companion object` which itself is inside of ScoresActivity.

```
class ScoresActivity: Activity() {
   // ...

   companion object {
      var trx: Int = 0 
   }
}
```

Usage (from any Activity):

```
ScoresActivity.trx = 5
```

Other ways would be another class which is a singleton ([`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) in Kotlin) and represents values which make up the game state or you pass the `trx` value via intents between Activities.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should't create Activity object using default constructor. Read about android core components.
2. You can store in as static value. Put it inside object to make it class variable. Read about instance/class variables.